# Updating combobox with filtered dataset at runtime using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to update the contents of a combobox while it is typed on. I'm using the code below but apparently I'm doing something wrong; the content doesn't get filtered and updated even on the debug console. The debug console only updates when I delete the last character in the combobox. Here is the code with the debug.writeline version (I will use the first record that comes up in the list in the combobox in the original code).

```
    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .Where(d => d.Field<string>("FirstName").StartsWith(comboBox1.Text))
            .Select(d => d.Field<string>("FirstName"));
        foreach (string s in query)
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Update: It looks like I had a problem with the database. The code above just works but it needs to be textchanged event, not textupdate.
Thanks for the contributions.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, the update method triggers every time the text in the combobox is changed but somehow I can't get the records.

Comment: What does it mean, returns `query.Any()` false?

Comment: Yes, it returns false. But when I delete the last character in the combobox it returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to handle the TextChanged event instead.

TextChanged: "Occurs when the Text property value changes." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx

TextUpdate: "Occurs when the control has formatted the text, but before the text is displayed."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.textupdate.aspx

Comment: Tried that just now but the result is the same. I think I'm missing some point here.

Comment: You might have a weird closure issue. Can you try declaring string s = combobox1.Text, and then using .StartsWith(s) ?

Comment: Tried that too, nothing changed.

Comment: I imagine that changing the data source of a combo box while editing its text does confuse the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to achieve some kind of autocomplete. Use a `TextBox` and work with its `AutoCompleteCustomSource`, `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource` properties instead.

Comment: Great tip thank you. I'll tinker with the code above a bit more and try that if I can't find a solution.

Comment: Combobox happens to have the same option. It turned out to be amazing. Just had to create a list and add the items to it.

Comment: It was my first thought to use it with the combo box; however, if its drop down list was only used for autocomplete then a text box would do it. But if you have to lookup an id, you still need a combo box.

Comment: I didn't know that. I don't need an id, just the text is suffice. Thanks again.